# Iteration over many-to-many data sets

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm almost there, but can't quite get all four of my scenarios. The following four hashtables represent the data I need to put into an object. In database terms, the relationship between node and roles is many-to-many.

The code works for `$testDataB` and `$testDataC` where there is one role per node, however, it does not increment the `RoleInstance` property as I'd expect, in `$testDataA` and `$testDataD`, where there are multiple roles per node.

#### Code

The code I am using to process the data scenarios is as follows (changing `$testDataX`accordingly):

```
$nodes = $testDataA.node
$nC = 0
$rC = 0
$oData =@()

foreach($node in $nodes)
{
    $rC++
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $node.nodeQty; $i++)
    {
        $nC++
        foreach($role in $node.roles)
        {
            $oData += [pscustomobject]@{
                NodeInstance = "Node$nC" 
                RoleInstance = "Role$rC"
                Roles = $role | select -ExpandProperty values
            }
        }
    }
}
$oData
```

---

The following shows the four data scenarios, with the expected output and the actual output obtained from the above code.

#### 1x node, 3x roles:

```
$testDataA = @(
    @{
        node = @{
            nodeQty = 1
            roles = @(
                @{role = "db"}
                @{role = "appsvr"}
                @{role = "client"}
            )
        }
    }
)
```

*Actual output:*

```
NodeInstance RoleInstance Roles 
------------ ------------ ----- 
Node1        Role1        db    
Node1        Role1        appsvr
Node1        Role1        client
```

*Required output:*

```
NodeInstance RoleInstance Roles 
------------ ------------ ----- 
Node1        Role1        db    
Node1        Role2        appsvr
Node1        Role3        client
```

---

#### 2x nodes, with 1x role each:

```
#2x nodes, with 1x role each.
$testDataB = @(
    @{
        node = @{
            nodeQty = 1
            roles = @(
                @{role = "db"}
            )
        }
    }
    @{
        node = @{
            nodeQty = 1
            roles = @(
                @{role = "appsvr"}
            )
        }
    }
)
```

*Actual output:*

```
NodeInstance RoleInstance Roles 
------------ ------------ ----- 
Node1        Role1        db    
Node2        Role2        appsvr
```

*Required output:*   Actual output is as required .

---

#### Total of 4x nodes, 1x node with 1 role and 3x nodes with 1 roles.

```
#total of 4x nodes, 1x node with 1 role and 3x nodes with 1 role.
$testDataC = @(
    @{
        node = @{
            nodeQty = 1
            roles = @(
                @{role = "db"}
            )
        }
    }
    @{
        node = @{
            nodeQty = 3
            roles = @(
                @{role = "appsvr"}
            )
        }
    }
)
```

*Actual output:*

```
NodeInstance RoleInstance Roles 
------------ ------------ ----- 
Node1        Role1        db    
Node2        Role2        appsvr
Node3        Role2        appsvr
Node4        Role2        appsvr
```

*Required output:*   Actual output is as required .

---

#### Total of 3x nodes, 1x node with 1 role, 2x nodes with 2x roles.

```
#Total of 3x nodes, 1x node with 1 role, 2x nodes with 2x roles.
$testDataD = @(
    @{
        node = @{
            nodeQty = 1
            roles = @(
                @{role = "db"}
            )
        }
    }
    @{
        node = @{
            nodeQty = 2
            roles = @(
                @{role = "appsvr"}
                @{role = "client"}
            )
        }
    }
)
```

*Actual output:*

```
NodeInstance RoleInstance Roles 
------------ ------------ ----- 
Node1        Role1        db    
Node2        Role2        appsvr
Node2        Role2        client
Node3        Role2        appsvr
Node3        Role2        client
```

*Required output:*

```
NodeInstance RoleInstance Roles 
------------ ------------ ----- 
Node1        Role1        db    
Node2        Role2        appsvr
Node2        Role3        client
Node3        Role2        appsvr
Node3        Role3        client
```

I've tried multiple permutations of locations for `$nC` and `$rC` as it seems to be these variables that have the greatest affect. I seem to be able to get A and D to work but then B and C don't or vice versa.

If anyone has any ideas, there'd care to pass my way, I'd be most grateful.
TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's not very elegant and there's a better way, but the following does what I need:

```
#Iterate over test data
$nodes = $testDataC.node
$nC = 0
$oData =@()
foreach($node in $nodes)
{
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $node.nodeQty; $i++)
    {

        $nC++
        $oData += [pscustomobject]@{
            NodeInstance = "Node$nC" 
            Roles = $node.roles
        }
    }
}

#Pull out unique roles and assign an ID for each role
$UniqueRoles = ($oData.roles | select role -Unique).role
$oUnique = @()
$uRC = 1
foreach($uR in $UniqueRoles)
{

    $oUnique += [pscustomobject]@{
        uRole = $ur#.role
        RoleId = $uRC
    }
    $uRC++
}

#Iterate over test data object, getting RoleId where it matches.
foreach($Node in $oData)
{
    foreach($role in $Node.roles)
    {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            NodeInstance = $node.nodeinstance
            RoleInstance = "Role$(($oUnique | Where-Object{$_.uRole -eq $role.role} | Select -First 1).roleId)"
            RoleName = $role.role
        }
    }
}
```

I'd be grateful to be shown a better way.

TIA